# How to navigate between screens using a button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

[image: code]

Hello, I want to navigate between windows using a button but not use a `NavigationLink`. It looks ugly.
this is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action()){
            Text("Hola")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.red)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Juan, please add your code as a code block, not as an image. People can't try your code if you share it as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an empty `NavigationLink` and bind your navigation flag or destination to your `Button`.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    
    @State var navigationFlag = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("First View")
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.navigationFlag = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("navigate")
                })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(),
                               isActive: self.$navigationFlag,
                               label: {
                                EmptyView()
                               })
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View")
    }
    
}
```