# Button click go another page in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have two view one is **LoginView**. Another is WelcomeView. I want to go from LoginView to WelcomeView onclick button from LoginView.

Here is my code..

1. LoginView

   ```
   struct LoginView: View {

    var body: some View {
      VStack{
       Button(action: {
           print("*** Press go login view ****")

       }) {
           Text("Login")
               .font(.custom(TextConstant.keyValues.front_name, size: 30))
               .foregroundColor(.white)
               .fontWeight(.bold)
               .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
               .padding(.all,20)
               .foregroundColor(.blue)
               .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .green]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
               .cornerRadius(10)
         }
        }
      }
    }
   ```
2. Here is WelcomeView

   ```
    struct WelcomeView: View {
      var body: some View {
       Text("Hello ")
      }
     }
   ```

I want to go another page on clcik button & back to previous onclick button. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate between screens using a button in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420653/how-to-navigate-between-screens-using-a-button-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try this to go from `LoginView` to `WelcomeView` on your button click in `LoginView`:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var showWelcomeView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: { showWelcomeView = true }) {
                    Text("Login")
                        .font(.custom(TextConstant.keyValues.front_name, size: 30))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.all,20)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .green]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                NavigationLink("", destination:  WelcomeView(), isActive: $showWelcomeView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

`NavigationView` iOS 13.0–17.2 Deprecated.

Use `NavigationStack` and `.navigationDestination(...)`, such as:

```
 struct LoginView: View {
     @State private var showWelcomeView = false
     
     var body: some View {
         NavigationStack {
             VStack {
                 Button(action: { showWelcomeView = true }) {
                     Text("Login")
                         .foregroundColor(.white)
                         .fontWeight(.bold)
                         .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                         .padding(.all,20)
                         .foregroundColor(.blue)
                         .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .green]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                         .cornerRadius(10)
                 }
             }
             .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showWelcomeView) {
                 WelcomeView()
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: NavigationView is deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types